# How to use volume's button to zoom in/out text in textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, zooming

How to override and use volume buttons to zoom IN/OUT text inside in layout, similar as when you are writing/reading SMS ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OpenClose);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
            float x = txt.getScaleX();
            float y = txt.getScaleY();

            txt.setScaleX(x - 1);
            txt.setScaleY(y - 1);
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
            float x = txt.getScaleX();
            float y = txt.getScaleY();

            txt.setScaleX(x + 1);
            txt.setScaleY(y + 1);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when zoom IN the text increasing, but overflow over the screen

Comment: your question states that  **zoom IN/OUT text inside in layout** . Next time think through a little before posting a question.

Comment: user3501749 - when you zoom out the text rotates 180 deg , I cant predict this result

Comment: you could do that in a simple If loop having a StoredValue and Storing a Int Value when user clicks the VOLUME_DOWN Button. if (StoredValue == SetValue) {// Do nothing;} . Well you could have thought that at least i suppose. And don't expect the users in stack over flow to give exact result you want. Probably you have work on it